# Expect throwError not getting coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

There is a `ValidationError` (custom made) being thrown on my `invert` function if no `string` is provided:

```js
const invert = (str) => {
  if (str === '') throw new ValidationError('String must no be empty.');
  return str;
};
```

This line of code is not getting full coverage by my assertion while using Jest:

```js
expect(() => invert('')).toThrow(ValidationError);
```

Is there a way to get coverage for this line?

Comment: I provided the wrong if! Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two test cases at least. One test throws an error, and one test is normal. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
export const invert = (str) => {
  if (str === '') throw new ValidationError('String must no be empty.');
  return str;
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { invert, ValidationError } from './';

describe('64271662', () => {
  it('should throw validation error if string is empty', () => {
    expect(() => invert('')).toThrow(ValidationError);
  });
  it('should return string', () => {
    expect(invert('teresa teng')).toBe('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64271662/index.test.ts (9.867s)
  64271662
    ✓ should throw validation error if string is empty (4ms)
    ✓ should return string (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.042s
```